Firebase sign-in not working with my app (Vue/Ionic)
I'm trying to create a user login/register system using Firebase on my Ionic app with Vue.
I have set up Firebase and authorized account creation, but despite this it does not work, I get the following error when I try to create an account on the /register page of my application:
auth.service.ts:20

POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=(mykey) 400 (Bad Request)


(anonymous) @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:1082await in (anonymous)_performFetchWithErrorHandling @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:1095_performApiRequest @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:1058_performSignInRequest @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:1130signInWithPassword @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:3149handleRecaptchaFlow @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:2956_getIdTokenResponse @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:3232_processCredentialSavingMfaContextIfNecessary @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:4242_signInWithCredential @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:4326signInWithCredential @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:4334signInWithEmailAndPassword @ firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:4548login @ auth.service.ts:20login @ LoginPage.vue:34(anonymous) @ LoginPage.vue:9cache..cache. @ chunk-YBIACCRJ.js?v=02c17099:12160callWithErrorHandling @ chunk-YBIACCRJ.js?v=02c17099:2305callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ chunk-YBIACCRJ.js?v=02c17099:2312invoker @ chunk-YBIACCRJ.js?v=02c17099:11195submitForm @ @ionic_vue.js?v=02c17099:1649Button2.handleClick @ @ionic_vue.js?v=02c17099:1542Show 17 more framesShow lessUnderstand this errorauth.service.ts:22 Error during login: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-email).at createErrorInternal (firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:699:37)at _fail (firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:664:9)at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:1119:9)at async _performSignInRequest (firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:1130:26)at async _signInWithCredential (firebase_auth.js?v=02c17099:4326:20)at async Object.login (auth.service.ts:20:13)at async Proxy.login (LoginPage.vue:34:13)`

Here's my auth.service.js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from 'firebase/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export const AuthService = {
    async register(email: string, password: string) {
        try {
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during registration:', error);
        }
    },

    async login(email: string, password: string) {
        try {
            await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during login:', error);
        }
    },

    async logout() {
        try {
            await signOut(auth);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during logout:', error);
        }
    }
};

my environments/environment.js  set up with my SDK informations :
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    firebaseConfig: {
        apiKey: etc
    }
};

and my firebase config is well imported in main.ts :
/* Firebase configuration */
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

I created my project and configured it in Firebase and imported the necessary information into my project, I tried to create a user via /register but it doesn't work. I also tried creating a user from Firebase and logging in with it via /login but that doesn't work either.
Do you have any clue so I can fix this?

Can you show how you call login in the rest of your app? Most likely you're not passing in the correct, valid email address there.
